# Microsoft Text Translator API always return empty content

Tags: api, microsoft-translator

I'm new to Microsoft Text Translator API, however after followed all instructions I found I always get "no content" from the text translator API.

Here is what I did:

1. I created subscription to microsoft translator text API (S1 Standard tier "Pay as you go") on azure and obtained key from it (key1).
2. I got access token from key1 using the tool here http ://docs.microsofttranslator.com/oauth-token.html.
3. Then I tried Translate API on http://docs.microsofttranslator.com/text-translate.html#!/default/get_Translate. The parameters I provided are

Text : 彼はジャッカスです。 (This is the example in the same page)

To   : en

Authorization : Bear [Access token]

However when I clicked "Try it out!" button, I always get

Response Body : no content

Response Code : 0

Response Headers : {"error" : "no response from server"}

the Request URL is : https://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/http.svc/Translate?text=%E5%BD%BC%E3%81%AF%E3%82%B8%E3%83%A3%E3%83%83%E3%82%AB%E3%82%B9%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%80%82&to=en

I suppose this is a "hello world" sample which should work, however it doesn't. Please let me know if there is anything wrong here, and how I can get it work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is something wrong with the documentation page at the moment. You can use other tools like Postman to try out the API. I just tried and it works fine.[image]